# PHP cURL - Multiple requests from same 'user'

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the content of a site hidden behind a standard login form (over HTTPS on both my site and the target site, if that matters).

I can successfully login to the page by doing a `POST` request like so:

```
include("inc/simple_html_dom.php");

$url = "https://account.tfl.gov.uk/Login";

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 60;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"UserName=USER&Password=PASSWORD&AppId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&ReturnUrl=");     

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I then want to be able to scrape the user's journey history, which is available at https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/journeyHistoryThrottle.do?_qs=_qv=[SESSION CODE] once logged in. To get the session code I use SimpleHTMLDom:

```
$html = str_get_html($result);
$codeRaw = $html->getElementById('Oyster')->childNodes(1);
$code1 = explode("?_o=",$codeRaw);
$code2 = explode('"',$code1[1]);
$codeReal = $code2[0];
```

I'm then trying to visit that page by doing another cURL request:

```
$url = "https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/journeyHistoryThrottle.do?_qs=_qv=".$codeReal;

echo $url;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 60;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,  1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);

$result = str_replace('"/','"https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/',curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;
```

But all I get is a login page again - I suspect because the two cURL requests generate different "sessions" on the TfL site??

Is there a way to force cURL to use the previous session? If it's relevant, I may also need to do further requests while navigating through the journey history pagination.

Or any other way to achieve this? (No API is provided by TfL for this purpose)

Comment: You don't have to set cookies again once you do the second curl request, just unset the posts and replace the url

Comment: How do I unset the posts? And which cookie-related line(s) need to be removed from the second curl?

Comment: You got the reply of @miken32

Answer (score 1):

For simple session handling, you need only set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option to an empty string. See more in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

A couple of possible issues that I see. Your two URLs are on different hosts, is that intentional, and if so are you sure that cookies from account.tfl.gov.uk will be read on oyster.tfl.gov.uk? You did not set your method from POST to GET on the second URL. I assumed that's a mistake, because there's no post data on the second retrieval, and corrected it below.

Also worth mentioning, that you may not be going about getting your `$codeReal` in the most efficient way, but I can't see the HTML your working with. All that `explode()` suggests there might be a better way!

```
<?php
include("inc/simple_html_dom.php");

$url = "https://account.tfl.gov.uk/Login";

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>10,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>60,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>"",
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>[
        "UserName"=>"USER",
        "Password"=>"PASSWORD",
        "AppId"=>"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "ReturnUrl"=>"",
    ],
];
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// get your code, be sure to escape it
$html = str_get_html($result);
$codeRaw = $html->getElementById('Oyster')->childNodes(1);
$code1 = explode("?_o=",$codeRaw);
$code2 = explode('"',$code1[1]);
$codeReal = $code2[0];

$codeReal = urlencode($codeReal);

$url = "https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/journeyHistoryThrottle.do?_qs=_qv=$codeReal";

// most of your options are the same, just change URL and disable POST
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
    CURLOPT_POST=>false,
];
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: thanks. Still no joy. I've also added the cookie file back in so it is generated again on the server (cookies.txt) and confirm that "oyster.tfl.gov.uk" is included (it is). May have to give up on this.